# Resizing a gtk2 widget with the mouse inside an area (window) with scroll?

Tags: gtk2

I wanted to develop a widget container (still on python 2.7 and gtk2), which would be placed in a scrolled window, and could be freely moved and resized in the window, such that: click & drag within the widget would move it inside the window; and when widget's corners / edges are visible in the window, it would expose drag handles for resizing - otherwise, if it is bigger than the window area, it would scale up and down (zoom in and out) on middle-click.

Of course, I want to keep the amount of custom coding of this widget to a minimum, so I though looking into what's available in gtk2 first. It turns out, the *only* element exposing resize drag handles is gtk.Window - and at that, *only* if it is a main (or root) window; otherwise, if a window is placed inside a widget, its size is apparently set by the widget, and so there are no drag handles (not menus, titlebars etc). I was wandering why this is - and it seems it is due to multiple document interface (MDI) being considered evil by gtk developers, see e.g. [Re: [gtk-list] Resizing widgets with a mouse](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-list/2000-February/msg00392.html) or [Does GTK support MDI? - Linux/BSD whirlpool.net.au](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/172422).

Just to demonstrate the behavior that I want, I used a PyQt4 code from [Python PyQt/PySide QMdiArea subwindows scroll not working in TabbedView - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18406962/python-pyqt-pyside-qmdiarea-subwindows-scroll-not-working-in-tabbedview), since as it turns out, Qt does have an MDI area. So here's the gist of it - if a corner is visible, a resize drag handle appears, and resize drag action can be started:

[image: qtdrag1]

When you thus drag the corner outside of the window - the scrollbars automatically indicate the new size/position of the inner widget (note the window got also moved a bit in this screenshot below, that was manual and unintended):

[image: qtdrag2]

Again, I don't really need a window (as in titlebars, menus) - just a widget container that would behave in this way, so I could put e.g. a table (e.g. TreeView) or an image in it, as the situation demands - and at least not worry about recalculating the "outer" scrollbars (naturally, I'd expect I'd have to code the rest of my custom behavior myself). Also, I just need a single widget placed in a window like that for now (so no "multiple document"s).

While Qt seems to offer this in a way, I don't have the possibility right now to get into it to the level of doing something like this; and the same goes for WxWindows (see e.g. [wxPython-users - How to resize Widgets?](http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/How-to-resize-Widgets-td2344515.html) - possible, but as there is no code there, I cannot see if geometry calculation coding is required or not).

So I was wondering - is there a widget I may have missed, that would implement the above behavior, and that I could take as a base for customization? If not, what options do I have to implement something like the above on gtk2 (eventually with Python)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this would work, but I suggest looking into [`GtkOffscreenWindow`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkOffscreenWindow.html); put the inner widget into that, and render it to a `GtkDrawingArea` inside a `GtkScrolledWindow`. This would probably make the scrollbars behave properly depending on the size of the drawing area.

What you won't get:

- window titlebars, you'll have to render those yourself because GTK doesn't know about them, they're part of the window manager. (Note, the inner window in the Qt example has a different titlebar than the outer window - I suspect this is the same thing.)
- drag handles to resize the window, you'll have to code those yourself, as you expected.

You might also want to look at how the Glade GUI designer does this.